# Вопрос по верстке, что делаеть если дизайнер сбросил макет с 5 стилями одного шрифта?

Tags: html, вёрстка, шрифты, веб-дизайн

Возник вопрос, получил макет psd, отдельно вынесены шрифты. 5 шт.
Захожу на гугл фонтс, как бы выбираю эти 5 семейств одного шрифта

[image: см. скриншот]

Гугл в ответ выдает код для вставки вида:

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700;800;900&display=swap');
</style>
```

С этим вроде все ясно-понятно.
**Но теперь сам вопрос** почему если я перехожу по ссылке которую выдал гугл фонтс в @import url (напомню я выбираю 5 семейств стилей одного Montserrat шрифта), то я вижу список в итоге что он будет тянуть 25 стилей?

Как это понимать?) И будут они занимать +4 мб на каждой странице сайта и стопорить всю загрузку?
Обьясните пожалуйста как вписать в макет шрифт чтобы он не тянул все...
Или я чего то не допонимаю и гугл фонтс загрузит не 25 стилей?

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700;800;900&display=swap
```

Я вижу:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WRhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}


/* cyrillic */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459W1hyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}


/* vietnamese */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WZhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wlhyw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}


/* cyrillic */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}


/* vietnamese */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}


/* cyrillic */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}


/* vietnamese */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}


/* cyrillic */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}


/* vietnamese */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraBold'), local('Montserrat-ExtraBold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* cyrillic-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Black'), local('Montserrat-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}


/* cyrillic */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Black'), local('Montserrat-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}


/* vietnamese */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Black'), local('Montserrat-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Black'), local('Montserrat-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Montserrat Black'), local('Montserrat-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: `И будут они занимать +4 мб на каждой странице сайта и стопорить всю загрузку` - почему? Они загрузятся только в первый раз, а потом будут кешированы.

Comment: Ну ладно даже один раз + 4 мб для магазина где и так много контента это существенно. Как получается что выходит туча шрифтов вместо 5 шт? Проще может отговорить вообще заказчика и дизайнера от использования гугл фонтс? и перейти на шрифты встроеные: system-ui,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Noto Sans,sans-serif;

Comment: @Максим отговорить заказчика не от гугл фонтс, а от любых кастомных шрифтов. Шрифты будут также весить, если вы их сами скачаете и подключите руками

Comment: `Как получается что выходит туча шрифтов вместо 5 шт?` - там не 25 шрифтов. Просто каждый из 5 шрифтов разбит отдельно на 5 частей, с разным набором символов. Ну, например, символы из `vietnamese` вы вряд-ли будете использовать. Посмотрите в настройках google, можно ли их вообще исключить.

Comment: Он загрузит только те стили, которые нужны. Обратите внимание на unicode-range

Comment: Точно,  unicode-range он должен указать браузеру какой диапазон символов загружать, буду знать спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, повырезал из того кода что выдает гугл оставил только шрифты /* cyrillic */
Размер стал допустимый.